# Inconsistent behaviour of MariaDB while using having, order by and limit without group by

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit, mariadb, having

### TL;DR

Always use `group by`.

### Problem description

I have a problem with `select` query that uses `having`, `order by` and `limit` in MariaDB:

`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.9-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

### Defintions

Let's suppose we have the following simple `test` table with two rows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `weight` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `x` INT(11) NOT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

INSERT INTO `test` (`weight`, `x`) VALUES (1, 33);
INSERT INTO `test` (`weight`, `x`) VALUES (1, 44);
```

And we also have a simple proxy function `TestProxy` that just passes through the first argument:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `TestProxy`;
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION `TestProxy`(
        x double(9,6)
) RETURNS double(8,2)
        NO SQL
BEGIN
        RETURN x;
END//
delimiter ;
```

### Working query with `where`

If I run the following select query using `where` condition, I expectantly get **one** row:

```
SELECT
    `test`.weight,
    `test`.x
FROM `test`
    WHERE 35 <= TestProxy(`test`.x)
ORDER BY weight ASC
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

### Non-working query with `having`

However, If I replace `where` with `having` I get **empty** set in MariaDB. In MySQL I expectantly get **one** row:

```
SELECT
    `test`.weight,
    `test`.x
FROM `test`
    HAVING 35 <= TestProxy(`test`.x)
ORDER BY weight ASC
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

### Working query with `having` but without `TestProxy` function

Furthermore, when I use `having` and I replace `TestProxy` with `test.x` again I expectantly get **one** row:

```
SELECT
    `test`.weight,
    `test`.x
FROM `test`
    HAVING 35 <= `test`.x
ORDER BY weight ASC
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

### Working query with `having` but wrapped with `select`

At last, when I wrap the query with `select` and move `limit` to the wrapper I expectantly get **one** row:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
    `test`.weight,
    `test`.x
FROM `test`
    HAVING 35 <= TestProxy(`test`.x)
ORDER BY weight ASC
) as table1
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

However, this query is very slow.

### Query with `having` that works depending on `order by`

After reading and analyzing answers of @slaakso and @gordon-linoff, I've investigated it even further, simplified the problem and realized that one row is returned only when it first appears on the result set that would be returned before applying `limit`.

So the following query will result with **one** row:

```
SELECT
    33 = TestProxy(`test`.x) as tp
FROM `test`
HAVING tp
ORDER BY x ASC
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

And the following query will result with an **empty** set:

```
SELECT
    33 = TestProxy(`test`.x) as tp
FROM `test`
HAVING tp
ORDER BY x DESC
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

### Working query with `having` and `group by`

If I add `group by` the query works as expected in MariaDB returning **one** row:

```
SELECT
    33 = TestProxy(`test`.x) as tp
FROM `test`
GROUP BY tp
HAVING tp
ORDER BY x DESC
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

### Summary

Could someone explain why is there inconsistency in MariaDB? Am I missing something or is that a bug in MariaDB?
I guess this has something to do with optimizing queries but I am not sure how to check it out.

<s>Does anyone have a suggestion to how to fix it? It is obviously a simplified example; I need `having` for my complex queries.</s>

Comment: Tried this with MySQL 5.6.27 and MariaDB 10.0.21. There is no difference how the versions worked. Mabye you are running different MySQL version and this explains it. Nevertheless, why not just use the WHERE-clause as HAVING is for the GROUP BY.

Comment: Do not use (m,n) on `DOUBLE`.  It will do extra roundings, especially in your example.  It could lead to equal values being treated as unequal.

Comment: What happens if you declare the `FUNCTION` to be `DETERMINISTIC`?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is very subtle. This is the query that "works" in MySQL but doesn't "work" in MariaDB:

```
SELECT `test`.weight, `test`.x
FROM `test`
HAVING 35 <= TestProxy(`test`.x)
ORDER BY weight ASC
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

My suspicion is around the use of an expression not in the `select` list, along with `having` without `group by`.

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html) explicitly states:

> Another MySQL extension to standard SQL permits references in the
>   HAVING clause to **aliased expressions** in the select list.

Nothing in your query is an aliased expression in the `select` list.

My guess is confusion due to the `having` being used without a `group by`.  Because the *expression* is not in the `select`, possibly MySQL/MariaDB is deciding to evaluate it once, on an indeterminate row, rather than once per row.  The difference in results between the two databases may simply be due to the row being chosen.

In any case, in any other database, `having` without a `group by` generally looks awkward.  `Having` without a `group by` and no aggregation functions is not allowed.

Comment: I've investigated that even though I use alliased expression in `having` from the `select` list the result set is still inconsistent (see  'Query with having that works depending on order by` section from my updated question).

Comment: @user3042620 . . . The edited question is hard to fathom.  `order by` should not change the number of rows in the result set.

Comment: MariaDB 5.3.3 and MySQL 5.6.4 both "detected and optimized away useless parts of a query".  (Dec, 2011)

Answer (score 0):

WHERE and HAVING are not interchangeable. HAVING should only to be used as a condition to GROUP BY. MySQL/MariaDB are quite liberal in terms of how SQL can be written and therefore do not issue a warning/error and you might sometime get unexpected results.

In your case, the function call seems to be executed after the ORDER BY / LIMIT combo causing the funtion only to receive the row with value 33.

Comment: . . In any database, `having` would be evaluated before row-limit operations (at least for `limit`, `top`, and `fetch`).

Comment: This is true, if the `having` is used with `group by` (as it should).

Comment: I think you are right. It definitely works when `group by` is used.
However, I still haven't found a resource indicating that `group by` is required and what happens when it is not used...

Comment: Also [this resource](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/having-clause/) says that if `group by` is omitted then `having` treats the table as a single group.

Comment: @user3042620 . . . Interesting.  MariaDB is generally quite consistent with MySQL and MySQL definitely does not follow that pattern.  My guess is that the documentation is misleading.  It is accurate when the `having` clause contains an aggregation function.